# Issue while uploading file with ftputil

Tags: python, python-2.7, ftp, ftputil

I am struggling to upload file to my FTP server. Please advise what is wrong in code below:

> **host:** someserver.com
>
> **path:** ./my_folder/at_this_server
>
> **target:** 'test.pdf'

```
with ftputil.FTPHost(ftp_settings['host'],
                     ftp_settings['user'],
                     ftp_settings['password'],
                     ftp_settings['port']) as ftp_host:
    safe_chdir(ftp_host, ftp_settings['path']) # change FTP dir
    ftp_host.upload_if_newer('local_test.pdf', 'test.pdf')
```

There is successfully execute the command `upload_if_newer()` or `upload()`, but I don't see any uploaded file to the FTP folder.

### UPDATE

I found that file is uploading to `host+"/my_folder"` only instead of `host+"/my_folder/at_this_server"`.

Comment: Do you have access to FTP server log? Can you include it to your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Check the result of `ftp_host.upload_if_newer('local_test.pdf', 'test.pdf')`. If it is `True` then the file was copied.
2) Are you sure that `safe_chdir` function is correct? You could check that current directory on FTP changed using `ftp_host.getcwd()`.  Try to upload file using full path instead of changing FTP dir.
3) Check access rights.